# Which is the safest way to talk to SharePoint servers of different versions?

Tags: sharepoint

I need to upload, download and manage files in SharePoint and there are [many ways to talk to a SharePoint server](http://www.shillier.com/archive/2010/08/31/uploading-and-downloading-options-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx), but what is the best one to choose to support different versions of SharePoint (2003, 2007, 2010...)?

Comment: Don't forget ADO.NET Connectors like http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/

Answer (score 1):

"Safe" is good, especially when you are talking about 2007, 2010 **and** 2003. The Sharepoint Architecture was fundamentally changed throughout the years and I don't know of anything which didn't changed with the different versions.

- WebDAV: Impossible to work with - Sharepoint actually implements its own WebDAV Protocol and not the standardized one. I'm not sure whether it changed throughout the years. But: All Sharepoint Versions included some kind of WebDAV, so it might be possible to leverage that.
- WebService: They're all different between the versions
- FrontPage RPC: UGH... No.
- Client OM: Is new in 2010.
- Custom WCF Service: Yes. Same goes for third party ADO.NET Connectors - leveraging the same functionality - Custom development.

The "safest" way as in standardized I would say are the **webservices**. You will still need to account for the different Sharepoint versions, but all of them had webservices. My second approach would be to code a custom WCF service, querying the object model - or use ADO.NET Connectors from third parties.

Comment: I believe you underestimate WebDAV. You could add a file from your local computer to a SharePoint 2003 library and you can still do it in SharePoint 2010. All you need is Windows Explorer, which is still the same.

Comment: You're right about that, but as I said Sharepoint is **not really** using standard WebDAV. I had many problems in accessing Sharepoints WebDAV functionality with different clients. That's why I noted it as "impossible to work with", but you are right that all versions support the special Sharepoint WebDaV.